# Laravel Public vs Storage directories for audio files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am a little bit confused about in which directory I should put my .mp3 files in Laravel 5.

- `public/`, my first choice as my MP3 can be considered as media (like images which are already stored there)
- `storage/app`, according to [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496301/laravel-5-0-folder-structure-public-vs-resources) this directory is kind of recommended for this purpose.

  [image]

I don't really mind being able to get an URL of these audio files since I serve it as a stream (to somehow prevent downloads, lol).

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess it just depends on whether you want direct public access or not.

`public/` is simpler. Anything in there you can link to directly. Just like your `js` or `css` or `images` resources.

`storage/app` is obviously more secure, no way to access it directly. That's what I would use (actually I think I'd do `storage/app/audio` to be specific) so I have more control over how they are accessed.

Comment: I think I saw something just the other day about Laravel adding a specific `storage/app/uploads` directory in 5.3. Taylor knows there's confusion over this. But it's just convention still, you can stick 'em where you want.