# Use Controller with my public folder in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I bought an template with HTMLs files, CSS and Javascript. Now I want to use Laravel 5.4 so I have **resources** folder and **public** folder.
After reading this

[Click here to redirect to the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496301/laravel-5-0-folder-structure-public-vs-resources)

I understood that all my CSS, Javascript that the template gave me I have to put into my public folder.

**What is the problem?** My index page (the page that is opened when the user enter in my site www.mysite.com) has to connect to the server to get some staditics data, and the index page is in public folder! If I make a controller for my index I need to put it into resource/view folder with index.blade.php

If I put my index page into resources/view my browser alway redirect to the index of public folder so...
I have a Headache for all of this, can you help me to solve my problem?

I think I'm not the first one that need to make a index with a controller to connect to my server.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I get your issue. Your template needs to be converted to blade syntax and use a controller to pass data to it for it to handle. How else would it work?

Comment: My template works only with html css and js, not need data to pass at today. I need to do that because in the template now is harcoded some value that now I need to get from my server

Comment: So just create a route to index.blade.php and put the code from the template file into that and update the directories?

Comment: `/public/` is for files you want to serve publicly like CSS, JS, images etc.

Comment: haha something like that yes. I put my index.html to my new index.blade.php, but now I have to redirect all my href css and js in my index.blade.php to ../public/css and ../public/js and I'm not sure that it is ok

Comment: That's what it's for...

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset - use this to access the `public` folder files

Comment: So there is no problem to redirect in my index.blade.php to  ../public/css? Ok I thought that it was not a good practices. But how I resolve the problem to go to my index.blade.php when the user type www.myhosting.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134327/discussion-between-faustino-gagneten-and-andy-holmes).

Comment: You create an index.blade.php, you then create a route for `/` to point to an indexController that serves your blade template. In your blade template you require your assets using `asset()`. Not all web apps are built the same, what you're asking to do is fine, if that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our conversation in the chatroom, it appears that you modified the `index.php` file that resides inside the `public` directory. This file *shouldn't* be changed or modified, this is partly what powers your Laravel app.

What you need to do is create your blade views, create a controller to return the view and create a route to that controller/view and you should be okay.

The `public` directory should only be for things you want to serve publicly - such as CSS files, JS files and template images. The actual structure code should be split into Blade views :)

Hope this helps!